How to create a docker container with React
I’m trying to build a docker container that installs react and its dependencies and then replicates those installations on my machine, so I don’t have to install the dependencies every time I want to create an application. But for some reason I’m not able to perform this "automatic" creation.. Can anyone help me, please?
PS: the react file structure is being created in the container, but not being replicated in my machine.
My Dockerfile:
FROM node:20.1.0 AS builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

RUN npx create-react-app react-app

FROM node:20.1.0

WORKDIR /app/react-app
COPY --from=builder /app/react-app .
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

compose.yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  app-dev:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules


My personal recommendation is not doing it like this. Work outside Docker entirely and only ADD the build output.

But doesn't this stray a bit from Docker's idea of ​​a "portable environment"? If I need to put this container on my server, would I have to create the folder structure there manually?

For development? Yes, absolutely. For deployment you get the exact same Docker image you would with the Dockerfile you have now. // But if you want containerized development environments, maybe check out Dev Containers.

You can do this but you should simply your dockerfile a bit.  I'd go with something like this:
    # Use an official Node runtime as a parent image
FROM node:20.1.0

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Create a React app
RUN npx create-react-app react-app

# Change to the app directory
WORKDIR /app/react-app

# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]

This will ensure that your React app's files in the container are mirrored to your local directory, and the node_modules directory is kept separate and avoids any conflicts.
